# Convert(int, value) causes error based on where clause

Tags: sql-server-2016

Following one works perfectly (notice convert):

```
select (select Twr_Kod from whm.CDN.TwrKarty where Twr_GIDNumer=Convert(int, value))
 from Workflow.ControlValues
 inner join Workflow.Controls on Controls.ID=ControlID and Controls.ValueTypeID=1
```

However if I will make it subquery if causes error on converting value:

```
select
(select (select Twr_Kod from whm.CDN.TwrKarty where Twr_GIDNumer=Convert(int, value))
 from Workflow.ControlValues
 inner join Workflow.Controls on Controls.ID=ControlID and Controls.ValueTypeID=1
  where ItemID=Items.ID
   for XML path(''))
    from Offers.Items
```

I thought that `where` will exclude some rows, so it shouldn't cause any issues with convert. Do you know what is the reason of that behavior and how to prevent it?

P.S. I've checked row from error message and it does not match `Controls.ValueTypeID=1` from `on` clause.

Comment: [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) was opened in 2010. No sign that they plan on changing it any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT (
                SELECT Twr_Kod
                FROM whm.CDN.TwrKarty
                WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT, Twr_GIDNumer) = TRY_Convert(INT, value)
                )
        FROM Workflow.ControlValues
        INNER JOIN Workflow.Controls ON Controls.ID = ControlID
            AND Controls.ValueTypeID = 1
        WHERE ItemID = Items.ID
        FOR XML path('')
        )
FROM Offers.Items;
```

Excluding based on `WHERE` depends on execution plan. If query optimizer decides to execute `WHERE Twr_GIDNumer = Convert(INT, value)` first then you will get error.